# Slow SQL delete in sybase iq

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sap-iq

I have a huge table with 6bn rows.

My delete command looks something like below

```sql
delete from [table name] 
where ( [col1] = value1 and [col2] = value2 ) 
   or ( [col1] = value3 and [col2] = value4 )
... ~250 more such conditions
```

This is running too slow even as I have HG index on both col1 and col2.

We are able to delete around 100k rows in 15 minutes.

Any suggestions how I can improve the delete performance.

Will a composite index (col1, col2) help?

Comment: how you obtain  the pair  (value1, value2)  (value3, value4) ?? ...   is possible get these pairs from a select a subquery ??  and which db you are really using .. mysql  or sybase?

Comment: I'm using sybase iq. Let's say I can not alter how I obtain these tuples but can modify this query itself.

Comment: OK  nut  but how you obatin the tuple??   .. is possible obtain these tuple form a subquery?? .. or store the tuple in  temp table ??'

Comment: I can store it in a temp table ..still would like to know what are you thinking wrt subquery/temp table.

Comment: i have poste an aswer

Answer (score 0):

The repeated  OR condition produce slow performance you could try to improve performance avoiding the use of several OR clause  for this

Tf you can store the pairs `(value1, value2), (value3,value4), ...  (valuen, valuen+1)` in a temp `table temp_table colA, colB` with composite index  on `colA,colB` you could try using delete with inner join

For Sybase the delete join syntax should be:

```
  DELETE
  FROM [table name]
  FROM [table name],temp_table
  WHERE [table name].col1 = temp_table.colA
  AND [table name].col2 = temp_table.colB
```

Be sure you have also a composite index on [table name] (col1, col2).

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you use `OR` in your condition, innodb will not use
   index.
2. Secondly, more indexes will slow down the delete command execution
   time.
3. Thirdly, your table is too huge, you need to optimize it by split it
   by date or some other symbol.

So, if you want to use index, may be you need to run delete command few times by splitting or condition, that will use index.

PS: use the composite index (col1, col2) will be faster.

And if your record that you want is not much.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

> If you are deleting many rows from a large table, you may exceed the lock table size for an InnoDB table. To avoid this problem, or simply to minimize the time that the table remains locked, the following strategy (which does not use DELETE at all) might be helpful:

```sql
# Select the rows not to be deleted into an empty table that has the same structure as the original table:
INSERT INTO t_copy SELECT * FROM t WHERE ... ;

# Use RENAME TABLE to atomically move the original table out of the way and rename the copy to the original name:
RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_copy TO t;

# Drop the original table:
DROP TABLE t_old;
```

Answer (score 0):

Deletes are expensive.  100k rows in 15 minutes is about 111 rows per second.  That is not necessarily bad, depending on many factors, which you do not explain in your question:

- What load is on the system?
- Are other queries interfering with the locks needed for the deletes?
- How many indexes are on the table?
- Are there foreign key references to the table?
- Are there `delete` triggers?

`delete` is an expensive operation.  In addition to the specific work needed for the `delete`, rows/pages need to be locked and the results need to be logged.

It is not clear that *finding* the rows is the cause of what you see as a performance problem.  And finding the rows is what indexes will help.  Of course, it *could* be the problem.  But it is not obvious.

In many databases, massive deletes are so slow that it is faster to recreate the table without the desired rows.  That is, this sequence can be much faster:

- Create a new table filtering the rows using `where`.
- Truncate the original table (make a backup copy first!).
- Reinsert the data in the table.